# Domestic Traveling while pending H1B extension

Tags: visas, air-travel

My H-1B visa expired on June 30, 2021, and my employer in the US applied for an extension on June 18, 2020. I have a trip within US next week, but my employer has not received the I-797 with the case number. I know that I'm allowed to stay and work in the US for at least 240 days, but I don't have evidence of having submitted the extension. Can you tell me if it is a risk to travel and what evidence can I show to demonstrate that the extension was submitted? Thanks!

Comment: Domestic travel should in theory not require any immigration checks at all, and so provided you have a valid passport you should be fine. I don't think it's in TSA's mandate to check immigration status. However: US Border and Customs patrols have a lot of leeway in the [100mile zone near a border](https://www.aclu.org/know-your-rights/border-zone/) so depending on where you're going and how you're travelling you may have some limited risk.

Comment: I work with hundreds of people on H1B status and never once heard of anyone being checked for immigration status on domestic flights. Not saying it can’t happen but it’s exceedingly rare.

Comment: You said your visa expired, but US visas are only for entry. Did your current I-94 expire?

Comment: Yes, my I-94 expire in the same date that the visa (June 30)